# New hard drive install

Tags: hard-drive

I am thinking about installing new hard drive in laptop I want to insall Ubuntu 14.04 do I need to insall any drives or othe programs 1st or can I just plug in new hard drive and install Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes, you can install the new HDD and boot the Ubuntu CD/USB and install.

Answer (score 1):

(Very) short answer: Yes.

Short answer: Yes, but you can't keep data.

Long answer: You most certainly can install a new compatible communications bus hard drive. Meaning, you can't install a SATA drive into an IDE port. However, you do not have the ability to save old data just by hotswapping drives.

If you want to save old data, you need to run a `dd` from the primary drive to the secondary drive. If you do not, just reinstall Ubuntu.